# nvm/node.js conflicting with Homebrew?

Tags: node.js, bash, homebrew

I just got a new mac and started installing things...I installed `nvm`, updated my `.profile` to:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```

then `nvm install stable` to install `node` and `npm`. I `npm install`ed a few things, everything was working fine.

I then ran `brew install elixir`. `brew` told me that it could not create symlinks. I ran `brew link elixir`, same error. After researching I decided to `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` which I believe `brew` depends on??? ***- I think this is when things went south.***

This allowed me to be able to successfully run `brew link elixir`...BUT now I cannot run `nvm`, `npm` or `node`. They all exist in my `$HOME` directory but I get `-bash: npm: command not found`.

I ran `brew doctor` and everything checked out ok.

**I am trying to install everything "correctly" without entangling myself in a web of permissioning.** Do I need to update my `node` `$PATH`s? Reverse the `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local` command and permission `brew` another way? Or maybe something really cool that I don't even know about?